# check the database change for using UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-ajax

I'm a very new to ASP.Net and AJAX also.

I'm programming a Forum. My `showcomment.aspx` page, I use Repeater to get comment from SQL Database and display them in each topic.

I use UpdatePanel to auto update the new comment inserted in Database.

```
<div onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');">
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
        <ContentTemplate>          
          <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterComment" runat="server">
            ....
          </asp: Repeater...>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp: UpdatePanel>
```

The function `UpdatePanel1_Load():`

```
public void UpdatePanel1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindRepeaterComment();
    }
```

It seems that need an `PageMethod` or `function` or `jquery`(but I've never write a jquery before) to realize when new row inserted into Database.

How can I check the database change and then apply to UpdatePanel???

UPDATE:

Take a look at my BindRepeaterCommment function below:

```
private void BindRepeaterComment(int idtopic)
    { 
        string sql = "select * from COMMENT where idTOPIC="+idtopic;
        DataTable comment = l.EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
        RepeaterComment.DataSource = comment;
        RepeaterComment.DataBind();
    }
```

I'm also recommended to user the Timer control to refread the UpdatePanel in every 5sec, but I just want it auto update when the database has changed( new row inserted)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually updating update panel:

Call this Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var UpdatePanel1 = '<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID%>';

            function ShowItems()
            {
               if (UpdatePanel1 != null) 
               {
                   __doPostBack(UpdatePanel1, '');
               }
            }       

</script>
```

EDIT:

*`You can user Timer control to refresh page for every 5 minutes`*

Set the **`Interval`** property to specify how often postbacks will occur, and set the **`Enabled`** property to turn the Timer on or off.

Comment: I add this script on my aspx page. Then I open the table in Database-> insert new row(manual)--> return on my webpage and wait--> but it's still not update until I fresh F5. Poor me, I'm very new to AJAX. I wonder if I do something wrong???

Comment: No..after you're trying to grab the comment from your databse you need to update the updatepanel or if it dosent works try the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: I still dont understand about "update the updatepanel", I mean I dont really know the syntax because it's my first time to work with AJAX, take a look a my UPDATE above, I've added the BindRepeater function, do you mean I add update the panel in BindRepeater function???

Comment: Yes..and there is nothing to do with ajax here..don't b panic..try cool.

Comment: Now go to updatepanel1 properties and set its UpdateMode is set to Conditional

Comment: I just set it to Conditional, and it still dont update even though I add a new row into Database?

Comment: after you're trying to add a new row in your database

Comment: thank for your help, but the function that I add the new row to Database is in another aspx page.